# Dynamically sizing the text in my application

Tags: android

I am developing in Android and I want my app to scale from a smart phone all the way to a big screen TV. I have been struggling to get the font sizes of my Buttons, TextViews, ListViews and Canvases to scale properly. So far I have been using a lot of custom methods to get the job (kind of) done.

At the moment, I am grabbing the pixels and pixel density from the Android device at run-time and doing quick calculations on them to get the proper font size. This is kind of working, but it is proving to be a little off AND I am having a hard time changing the font on more complicated objects like ListViews that communicate through ArrayAdapters. Is this the best I have? Or is there a more reasonable solution for having my app text sizes scale properly between all sizes of devices?

Current state of my program:

Tablet:

- Screen Resolution: 1280x800
- Pixel Density: 1
- Calculated font size: 61sp
- Appearance: layout looks good

Phone:

- Screen Resolution: 1920x1080
- Pixel Density: 3
- Calculated font size: 27sp
- Appearance: Mostly good. Not a perfect scale since it isn't the same ratio as the tablet

Static methods:

```
public static Point GetScreenDimensions(Context context){
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    return size;
}

public static void SetTextSize(Context context){
    TEXT_SIZE_CANVAS = GetScreenDimensions(context).y/15;
    TEXT_SIZE_ACTIVITY = (GetScreenDimensions(context).y/13) / (int) GetScaledDensity(context);
}

public static float GetScaledDensity(Context context){
        return context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
}
```

Application in activity (method docs says it sets the int provided as an sp value):

```
btnManageTeams.setTextSize(Constants.TEXT_SIZE_ACTIVITY);
```

Result:
Text sizes that are mostly device agnostic.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Supporting Multiple Screens documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#support) - they have a section talking about naming conventions for your folders, so you can do it based on Density (`ldpi`, `xhdpi`, etc. but they also have `tvdpi`).

Anyway, for different sized text, buttons, etc. you can put the respective `drawable`s in their own folder, and then just use a single `layout` file and let the system pull the correctly sized `drawable`.  These `drawable`s may be images, 9-patches, or XML files (where you can define things like font-size, different colors).  For example, if I have a layout with a save icon, then my layout just calls the `ic_save`, but then my different folders are:

drawable-mdpi/

- ic_save.png (say this is 10px wide)

drawable-hdpi/

- ic_save.png (then this would be 20px wide)

drawable-xhdpi/

- ic_save.png (and this would be 25px wide)

---

Here are a handful of other helpful links specifically regarding designing for TV:

- http://developer.android.com/design/tv/index.html
- http://developer.android.com/training/tv/index.html
- https://developer.android.com/design/tv/patterns.html
- https://developer.android.com/design/tv/principles.html
- http://www.google.com/design/spec-tv/android-tv/introduction.html#
- http://www.google.com/design/spec-tv/design-principles/designing-for-tv.html#

Comment: I will read that page soon. Is mdpi, hdpi, and xhdpi decided by the pixel density of the device being used?

Comment: @Shadoninja Correct, any device will fall into one of those categories of density, so you should provide resources sized appropriately for each